# Python: Set permissions for pip or conda in /opt directory

Tags: python, pip, conda

I installed python via Anaconda to my `/opt` directory (I heard that's the proper way when all users should be able to use it).

Everything is working fine so far, up to the point when I try to install packages via pip or conda. Than I get permission issues for both ways.
When I try to do:

```
sudo pip install pandas-datareader
```

I get:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

and the same error results if I try to use `conda` as well.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/opt` folder is not in the global path, so when you `sudo` it is not available.

You may want to `sudo -E` to preserve any environment variables, which will likely include a customization to the `PATH` variable to include the directory where `pip` is installed in `/opt`

Alternatively, you can give the full path to the command `sudo /opt/anaconda-path/bin/pip`

Comment: For me `sudo -E /opt/anaconda-path/bin/conda install package-name` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `conda` or `pip` with `sudo`. Just run `pip install pandas-datareader`.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i get the permission error when i try to run the pip install command

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because 'sudo' uses its own secure path and not user's path determined by bash environment variable PATH. sudo's secure path is mentioned in the /etc/sudoers file by a variable named "secure_path".
In order for the sudo to see pip/conda, you should ask your administrator to add "/opt/anaconda/bin" to the secure_path variable.
That should fix the issue. Hope it was helpful.
Here is what a typical sudoers file may look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFVlL.png)